# Error with library swappy when building Unity project

Tags: unity-game-engine, build

I ended working on my project, and wanted to build it, but i got errors and tried to solve they by myself, i watched videos, look for another solves of my problems, but nothing hepled me. I really hope that the smartest community in Stack overflow will help me to don't lost my job, thank you!
So there is the error that i got after build:

`[CXX1212] D:\WinXGame2\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\cpp\CMakeLists.txt release|arm64-v8a : User is using a static STL but library requires a shared STL [//games-frame-pacing/swappy] See the Console for details.`

in console i have 2 errors, these are they:

error 1:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':unityLibrary:configureCMakeRelWithDebInfo[arm64-v8a]'.
> [CXX1212] D:\WinXGame2\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\cpp\CMakeLists.txt release|arm64-v8a : User is using a static STL but library requires a shared STL [//games-frame-pacing/swappy]

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

error 2:

```
D:\Unity\Hub\Editor\2023.2.9f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe -classpath "D:\Unity\Hub\Editor\2023.2.9f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-7.6.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

Environment Variables:
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE = AMD64
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_YELLOWBUCKET_DEV = 48835b4d1f5e342aefe5f016324d296a
BURST_ANDROID_MIN_API_LEVEL = 23
DriverData = C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
USERDOMAIN = DESKTOP-FKMNRR7
CommonProgramFiles(x86) = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
COMPUTERNAME = DESKTOP-FKMNRR7
DEBUG_ENV_VAR = UnityHub
LOGONSERVER = \\DESKTOP-FKMNRR7
AMPLITUDE_TOKEN_GREENBUCKET_PROD = yyzPzalJDwrQcYNuOZam0bhKb26WyyhK
PUBLIC = C:\Users\Public
ProgramData = C:\ProgramData
SESSIONNAME = Console
AMPLITUDE_TOKEN_YELLOWBUCKET_PROD = Ph-837Q6GNodAkyc2MRkxVPUcjlIET4d
ALLUSERSPROFILE = C:\ProgramData
SystemRoot = C:\Windows
windir = C:\Windows
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_REDBUCKET_DEV = 46b8b46515e7632fc42a504b72e05fd0
ProgramFiles(x86) = C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramW6432 = C:\Program Files
OS = Windows_NT
ANDROID_NDK_ROOT = D:\Unity\Hub\Editor\2023.2.9f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER = AMD64 Family 23 Model 96 Stepping 1, AuthenticAMD
HEAP_CLIENT_TOKEN_STAGING = 3786794399
HOMEPATH = \Users\Acer
GIT_LFS_PATH = D:\Git LFS
CHROME_CRASHPAD_PIPE_NAME = \\.\pipe\crashpad_31308_PNQPDKSUDYAHSRRJ
PROCESSOR_LEVEL = 23
CommonProgramFiles = C:\Program Files\Common Files
JAVA_HOME = D:\Unity\Hub\Editor\2023.2.9f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE = DESKTOP-FKMNRR7
TEMP = C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Temp
ProgramFiles = C:\Program Files
CommonProgramW6432 = C:\Program Files\Common Files
AMPLITUDE_TOKEN_YELLOWBUCKET_DEV = wKi8foVigDditGFvmZewRFWsEbX9Y0YO
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_GREENBUCKET_DEV = 3ded2a762163603391a425f688f990c8
PyCharm Community Edition = C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.3.2\bin;
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_REDBUCKET_PROD = ca12bb461ea96f9bdf5df4ded7d52994
VBOX_HWVIRTEX_IGNORE_SVM_IN_USE = 1
HOMEDRIVE = C:
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_STAGING = 83ee04fccc67e4fcc7dd527c4c6f1e21
USERNAME = Acer
OneDrive = C:\Users\Acer\OneDrive
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_YELLOWBUCKET_PROD = e03a9bbe92dc38a88cdb068d24c65b46
PATHEXT = .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
AMPLITUDE_TOKEN_REDBUCKET_PROD = QqyoFpcWPi7V17p80_46CF6-sNGRGbHo
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS = 12
AMPLITUDE_TOKEN_GREENBUCKET_DEV = 84H2gMm_FJzhr3mBaX1lM1JVukmCM7d9
AMPLITUDE_DEPLOYMENT_KEY_RED_BUCKET_DEV = client-wbjHYrmeSR87GmWOE7LDpf7sUySOIKHm
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_GREENBUCKET_PROD = c86fea37a9e1d3f0878b96e15b111c7c
ComSpec = C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
TMP = C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Temp
ORIGINAL_XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = undefined
PROCESSOR_REVISION = 6001
AMPLITUDE_DEPLOYMENT_KEY_RED_BUCKET_PROD = client-zH8Y7OK1i331EKuG77C6UxN8ygcM6LzS
AMPLITUDE_TOKEN_REDBUCKET_DEV = U4PSN7S7PuYVRODivvdcFwbu8R6IHGqa
SystemDrive = C:
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY = 28f3cae0b33b8b3702120c9ed1a935aa
OneDriveConsumer = C:\Users\Acer\OneDrive
SENTRY_ACCESS_TOKEN = 3df78d9e53f8456aa90fbae044ce1a6261421ab1d0014674bc2e933477289017
HEAP_CLIENT_TOKEN = 1717415662
APPDATA = C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Roaming
Path = C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.12.7-hotspot\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;D:\Git\cmd;D:\Git LFS;C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.3.2\bin;;C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Acer\.dotnet\tools;D:\Git;C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin
PSModulePath = C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
LOCALAPPDATA = C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local
USERPROFILE = C:\Users\Acer
WOOTRIC_CLIENT_TOKEN = NPS-aa8be4c3


stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':unityLibrary:configureCMakeRelWithDebInfo[arm64-v8a]'.
> [CXX1212] D:\WinXGame2\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\cpp\CMakeLists.txt release|arm64-v8a : User is using a static STL but library requires a shared STL [//games-frame-pacing/swappy]

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
]
stdout[
> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:extractProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:writeReleaseApplicationId UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:analyticsRecordingRelease
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:desugarReleaseFileDependencies UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeExtDexRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:collectReleaseDependencies UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:sdkReleaseDependencyData UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:validateSigningRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:writeReleaseAppMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:writeReleaseSigningConfigVersions UP-TO-DATE

> Task :unityLibrary:configureCMakeRelWithDebInfo[arm64-v8a] FAILED
C/C++: D:\WinXGame2\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\cpp\CMakeLists.txt release|arm64-v8a : com.google.prefab.api.NoMatchingLibraryException: No compatible library found for //games-frame-pacing/swappy. Rejected the following libraries:
18 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 16 up-to-date
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <c5ab5df75e57425eb4949046d4e04d0a>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <c5ab5df75e57425eb4949046d4e04d0a>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <c5ab5df75e57425eb4949046d4e04d0a>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <c5ab5df75e57425eb4949046d4e04d0a>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle androidGradle, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <c5ab5df75e57425eb4949046d4e04d0a>:0)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle androidGradle, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <c5ab5df75e57425eb4949046d4e04d0a>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <c5ab5df75e57425eb4949046d4e04d0a>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <c5ab5df75e57425eb4949046d4e04d0a>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
```

i have been working on my project about 2 months, and all these errors got me when i updated Unity on version 2023.2.9f1
I cant lose my project, I can't stand this, please help me, please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good afternoon,

the answer which solved the same problem that I had is here:

https://forum.unity.com/threads/android-build-error-user-is-using-a-static-stl-but-library-requires-a-shared-stl.1449946/

**Step 1:**
Disable the option "**Optimized Frame Pacing**":

Unity Documentation:
[https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsAndroid.html](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsAndroid.html#:%7E:text=Optimized%20Frame%20Pacing,Supported%20Aspect%20Ratio)

**Step 2:**
Add **namespace `com.unity3d.player`** to mainTemplate.gradle file

```
android {

**namespace 'com.unity3d.player'**

ndkPath "NDKPATH"
```

I hope this solve your problem.

**NOTE:** I am using Unity 2023.2.12f1